# How do I leave a user logged in after refreshing the page?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I am making a mini application with the Auth system. On the backend, I use the NodeJS and JWT token that I put in the Cookie and check it and make protected middleware. It all works great for me, but on the frontend (React) when I log in everything works until I refresh the page, when I refresh it the user is an empty object and my state is reset. How do I keep a logged-in user even after refreshing the page?

This is my React Reducer:

```
export const userLoginReducer = (state = { user: {} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, isAuthenticated: false };
    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, isAuthenticated: false, error: action.payload };
    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return { loading: false, isAuthenticated: false, user: null };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is my React Action:

```
const { data } = await API.post(
  '/api/v1/users/login',
  { email, password },
  config
);



 dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
} catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

API is config for Axios:

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
  withCredentials: true,
  credentials: 'include',
});
```

And this is my Login Screen:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/';

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin);
  const { loading, error, isAuthenticated } = userLogin;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      history.push(redirect);
    }

    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, history, redirect, error]);

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(login(email, password));
  };
```

I am new into React so if can someone help me i will be happy.

Comment: I think you can use cookies for that.

Comment: Store the token somewhere, like cookie or localStorage.

Comment: @SinanYaman i store token in cookie

Comment: @MarekBartczak okay?

Answer (score 0):

One of available options is providing an additional authorizing endpoint.

1. User sends request e.g. to `/user` or `/auth` right after entering a page
2. You read cookie on the server and return a decoded (from cookie) user data object
3. Based on response - you either log user in or you don't (if you found no cookie data or it was forged)

Comment: I’ve been thinking about it too, but I wouldn’t know how to write that code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your user login information on the client-side.

As a solution, you can save the user token, username, id, ... with the browser `localStorage` and get it when you need them.

But, the proper solution is to use some persistor like `redux-persis` to save your whole state, or a slice of it to avoid losing information on the redux store after refresh pages. behind the scene, `redux-persist`, uses the `localStorage` to save your store object.

More information about the `redux-persis` and how to implement it is [here](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#quickstart).